# Restructured text: Fall back if doctest module is missing

Tags: github, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

It seems that Github does not support the [sphinx.ext.doctest](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/doctest.html) syntax in their reStructuredText renderer, which is causing some problems when trying to include a *doctest-style code block* (`.. doctest`) in a README.rst which is transcluded into the documentation index (which is rendered by sphinx). If I replace the `.. doctest` directive with something else, it doesn't render properly as a doctest on Sphinx, but if I don't *remove* the directive, the code block doesn't render *at all* (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9485865443ec6817034b)).

Ideally I'd like to find a solution which just does the right thing in both environments, but failing that, is there a way to fall back to a `.. code` block or some other supported format (e.g. the rST equivalent of a `<NoScript>` tag)?